# Tool to monitor in and out data network traffic w graphs and detailed stats

Tags: linux, debian, networking, statistics

Is there a tool, that can gather stats on network usage?

Requirements:

- Generate HTML (or other format, convertible to HTML)
- Time line graphs for bandwidth usage, also which hosts use the most bandwidth and what port is used by that host.
- Which ports are using most bandwidth

This isn't the full requirements, but things I can think of just now.

I am not sure what the name of this kind of tool is called.

Answer (score 3):

The defacto standard for this is undoubtedly [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/). There are certainly alternatives out there such as [cacti](http://cacti.net/) or [HotSaNIC](http://hotsanic.sourceforge.net/).

It's also not hard to whip up your own. I use [collectd](http://collectd.org/) to monitor lots of different statistics including network traffic on hosts and even other devices on three continents, then whip up my own graphs using the related `rrdtool graph` tool.